# How and why does sample frequency Fs be mapped to 2π?

Tags: dsp-puzzle

Q1: Can anyone give a further explanation on this sentence?

> Each time $f_o$ is a multiple of $F_s$, the argument of the exponential is a multiple of $2\pi$

Q2: - must $f_o$ be a multiple of $F_s$?

[image]

[image: Picture 2: Why does Fs map to 2π?]

Comment: Instead of editing your question to add more questions I recommend opening a new question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question:

> Can anyone give a further explanation on this sentence? “Each time $f_o$
> is a multiple of $F_s$, the argument of the exponential is a
> multiple of $2\pi$”

This is a simple result based on the provided expression:
$$e^{j2\pi \left[\frac{f_o}{F_s}\right]n}$$

Let $f_o = mF_s$, where $m$ is an integer, then:
$$e^{j2\pi \left[\frac{f_o}{F_s}\right]n}$$
$$e^{j2\pi \left[\frac{mF_s}{F_s}\right]n}$$
$$e^{j2\pi mn}$$
and now the term in the exponent is equal to $j2\pi$ times an integer $mn$.

Your second question:

> And another question - must $f_o$ be a multiple of $F_s$?

No, $f_o$ is unconstrained subject to the answer to your first question.

Comment: Thanks a lot！ And I have 2 more questions

Comment: @Ran Instead of editing your question to add more questions I recommend opening a new question to ask.

Comment: [three new questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/questions-about-the-sampling-frequency-mapping-relation-to-2%cf%80)